# PHP User System Security

Tags: php, security, cookies, authentication

I have a small internal website for a charity, it's were the staff login to access documents and rota. Although it's only meant for certain users it is on the web so it's public therefore I'm still thinking about security. I need your opinions on the following because I'm not very experienced.

I've always stored two cookies when the user logs in. The first is their user id and the second a cookie id so people can't just change the user id and be logged in the cookie id needs to match. It's compared to the database every page. The problem is the cookie id is just a random number it will take no time for a PC to cycle through a range of a few hundred thousand combinations to find the matching ID for each user. So how can I stop this? Would PHP's uniqid be good enough?

What other attacks should I consider, apart from SQL Injection (already prevented)

Thanks

Comment: This looks like it might be of interrest in your case: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-totally-secure-cookies

Answer (score 0):

Store the client IP of each session on the server.
If the client IP for a session changes, then that's suspicious.

Another thing would be to give sessions a lifetime.
Like, invalidate a session if nothing happened for an arbitrary amount of time.

Last but not least, do only store a random ID in the session database and map that to the user instead of storing the user-id directly into a cookie.

Comment: based on the last comment what happens if a valid ID gets guessed then someone has access to a user's account.

Comment: @AnotherUser no, you're still matching the ID to the client IP. It could only be stolen if the break in attempt came from the same IP as the properly logged in client.